# Can't use pip anymore

Tags: windows, windows-10, anaconda, pip

In my anaconda environment I can't use pip anymore

```
(roo_env) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\roomfinder>pip install csvkit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.main'

(roo_env) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\roomfinder>python3 -m pip --version

(roo_env) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\roomfinder>pip3 --version
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(roo_env) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\roomfinder>pip3 --version
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(roo_env) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\roomfinder>pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.main'
```

I don't know if it is a problem with my environment variables. Here is my path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\
```

Comment: If you run `conda list`, what is the output? Could you add that to the question?

Comment: Also just to note, it looks like you have both a virtualenv as well as a conda environment activated. Could you try to deactivate them both (using `deactivate` for virtualenv and `conda deactivate` for conda. Then only make sure that the conda environment is activated.

Comment: @Randomhero the `(base)` one? Sure! Still gives the same

Comment: Hmm ok. Could you post the output of `conda list`?